# Can I use DataGrid in web assembly?

Tags: uno-platform

I have been trying to get data grid control to work in my web assembly project. The data grid control works fine in UWP but in web assembly, it just shows the headers of the list but no list items. (The headers show even if they are auto-generated).

Can I even work with DataGrid in web assembly or do I have to use the ListView for tables(or something else) or is it my code?

The NuGet package that I am using: Uno.Microsoft.Toolkit.Uwp.UI.Controls.DataGrid 
 (5.1.0-build.200.gf9c311b069)

```
<controls:DataGrid
                    Height="250"
                    HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                    VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
                    AutoGenerateColumns="False"
                    ItemsSource="{Binding OpenCaseList}">
                    <controls:DataGrid.Columns>
                        <controls:DataGridTextColumn
                            Header="Id"
                            Binding="{Binding Id}" />
                        <controls:DataGridTextColumn
                            Header="Title"
                            Binding="{Binding Tittel}" />
                        <controls:DataGridTextColumn
                            Header="Comment"
                            Binding="{Binding Comment}" />
                    </controls:DataGrid.Columns>
                </controls:DataGrid>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, this control is not yet implemented for WASM.

There's already an issue on GitHub for this. I suggest you upvote it and subscribe to it so you can track the progress and also provide any feedback.

Here's the link: https://github.com/unoplatform/uno/issues/1943

Comment: A thank you for the replay, I will definitely do that.